# pass parametes in angularJs in GET method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I am trying to send parameters in GET method in angularJs.

```
$scope.callMethod  = function(url , paramName1, paramName2 ,paramValue1 , paramValue2)
      {

     $http.get('rest/'+url+'?cd='+ (new Date()).getTime(),{params:{paramName1:paramValue1 ,paramName2:paramValue2}}).success(function(data)
                    {
                        console.log("in success block");   
                    }).error(function(data)
                    {
                        console.log("in error block");
                    }
                    );
          }
```

Here I provide the value of all the variables including the **paramNames** because I want this method to be **reusable** but during debug in browser I see that paramValues are being appended in correct way but paramNames are hardcoded. URL is as follows:

```
http://localhost:7001/MyWeb/rest/getProj?cd=1419222398177&paramName1=666560&paramName2=1
```

I have provided correct URL mapping in my spring controller. If gives me the error

```
 406 (Not Acceptable)
```

Kindly tell me that is it not possible to provide **keys** as variables in URL. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `$http` is using the keys of the `params` object as the query string keys, so when you define an object literal inline, like you did, the string `paramName1` became the actual key.

If you want to use the value of `paramName1` to be the key, prepare your `params` object like so:

```
var params = {};
params[paramName1] = paramValue1;
params[paramName2] = paramValue2;
```

and then call `$http`:

```
$http.get('rest/' + url + '?cd=' + (new Date()).getTime(), {
    params: params
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables for the keys in objects, you'll just have to stringify them before hand. You can do something like New Dev suggested, which will call .toString on the variable in brackets. Or you can explicitly call JSON.stringify:

```
var params = {};

params[JSON.stringify(paramName1)] = paramValue1;
params[JSON.stringify(paramName2)] = paramValue2;
```

Using JSON.stringify is more robust, and won't return something like `[object Object]`